# Has Pakistan been able to sell JF-17 fighter jets to Sri Lanka?

Tags: pakistan

Pakistani PM is visiting Sri Lanka.

There has been a lot of discussion in the news media about the selling of JF-17.

Some says that India is putting pressure on Sri Lanka not to buy jets from Pakistan and hence they are not buying. Some says that Sri Lanka hasn't bought JF-17 but committed. Some says contract has been signed for 8 jets.

What is actually going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you see the [wiki page of the jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAC/PAC_JF-17_Thunder#Operators) and see the operators, you will see Sri Lanka is not an operator. The Sri-Lankan Government has denied that any such matter came up in talks with the Pakistani officials however they added that they were still looking to purchase new fighters.

Quoting the [Columbo Gazette](http://colombogazette.com/2016/01/07/government-says-no-jf-17-deal-with-pakistan/):

> The Government has denied reports that it has struck a deal with
>   Pakistan for the purchase of JF-17 Thunder fighter jets, The Hindu
>   newspaper reported.
>
> **“The matter did not even come up for discussion during the talks [with**
>   **the Pakistani government],”** Karunasena Hettiarachchi, Defence
>   Secretary, told The Hindu , **adding that his government was still**
>   **considering the purchase of fighter jets**.
>
> Terming the reports as “incorrect,” Mahishini Colonne, spokesperson of
>   the Ministry of Foreign Affairs, responded, saying that “if there
>   arises a requirement for Sri Lanka to procure aircraft of this nature,
>   in keeping with the policy of the Government of Sri Lanka to maintain
>   transparency, expressions of interest will be called for, from all
>   concerned.”

Some sections of the press have however speculated that deal was in fact on the table but Indian pressure forced the Sri-Lankans to reconsider.

Quoting [the diplomat](http://thediplomat.com/2016/01/revealed-why-sri-lanka-backed-off-the-sino-pakistani-jf-17-thunder/):

> According to The Indian Express, the Sri Lankan government, led by
>   President Maithripala Sirisena, canceled its plans to purchase the
>   JF-17s after a “diplomatic missive” from New Delhi suggesting that
>   Colombo should refrain from adding these aircraft to its fleet.